# Extract all URLs that start with http or https and end with html from text file

Tags: regex, url, grep

I would like to extract every link that starts with http:// (not sure if I have https:// inside) and ends with .html from a text file using grep command.

Problem that I have is that file is too big and there are a lot of links...

I tried this:

```
grep "/http:\/\/.*?\.html/"  filename.txt > newFile.txt
```

but I get an empty file, just like with this:

```
grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9]./(html)" filename.txt > newFile.txt
```

Can anyone help me?

Just to be sure that we are on the same track, I want to extract all links to new file and have them 1 per line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
grep -Eo "https?://\S+?\.html" filename.txt > newFile.txt
```

This will match 1 or more non-space character after `https://` and before `.html`

Comment: Wow, this is it, do you mind explaining what is that S+? and how can I add extra argument for unique links? I mean to have only unique links in that new file

Comment: To get uniques links use: `grep -Eo "https?://\S+?\.html" filename.txt | sort -u > newFile.txt`

Comment: One more thing: how can I exclude all links if they have "search" word in it? Thank you.

Comment: You can use `-P` (perl regex) option in `grep` using `grep -Po 'https?://(?!\S*?search)\S+?\.html' filename.txt`

Comment: Nope, but thank  you. I have what I want (mostly)... there weren't that many links with "search" word in it...

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```
grep -oE '(http|https)://(.*).html' filename.txt > newFile.txt
```

but, if we have two links in one line we take both this links in one line

```
http://site1.com/1.html</a>tralala<a href="http://site2.com/2.html
```